# Magento Automatic Login from a Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, magento

I have an app in Laravel, with store items displayed on the first page linked to products on a Magento store. I can easily access the Magento DB from the Laravel app.

My question is, if a user is logged in on my Laravel app, when he/she clicks on a Magento store product(that is displayed on my Laravel app), he/she is redirected to the Magento store, and I would like to automatically log in that user in Magento, so he/she doesn't have to register/login again.

I've seen some examples online, but none of them explain what exactly I need to use. If I need to use the Magento REST API on my Laravel app, if I need to code directly in the Magento base-code somewhere..

Any help or a step-by-step tutorial that will at least get me started?

Answer (score 0):

About automatic login for Magento, I'm not sure what you mean there. The user will need to enter a username/password at some point in the flow. If you're looking for a single sign on solution, then Magento has this built-in. Hopefully you are not on an old version of Magento.

You do this through a Magento integration.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html

You want to redirect the Laravel user to Magento with middleware that initializes an OAuth handshake and then asks the user to login on the Magento url. The user is then redirected back to Laravel with an encrypted token. Both systems share the same token encryption string and so each one can verify the user is authentic by encrypting their token using the same settings.

Implementing OAuth is beyond a simple answer like this so I encourage you to understand the whole specification and flow.

https://oauth.net/2/

After redirecting back to Laravel, you can then check the user's token and verify they are logged in. If the token does not pass authentication you can redirect the user again through the OAuth process.